# Best Datatype for a variable that holders numbers and a dash "-"

Tags: mysql

Whats the best MySQL datatype for my variable that holders numbers and a dash in it (-).  Example would be 1233-33214-543-5435643

I'm New to StackOverflow, so whoever down-voted my question, can you please explain why? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an [**XY problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you maybe give us a little more information on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: When dealing with numbers, a dash usually means negative. Is that all you're trying to deal with is negative numbers?

Comment: Thanks Guys. What I'm trying to do is hold a unique number for users, the number looks like "5432543-88367-87366-637622". I recok a varchar would be good isnt it?

Comment: The question probably got downvoted becuase it didn't make any sense before, and you didn't provide much detail. But now with the MySQL clarification, and example string, it makes more sense.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for being nice to the newbee man :D I think there should be a comments option when someone down-votes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention `VARCHAR`, it sounds like you want a [MySQL datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html), not a [PHP datatype](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) then.  In that case, it sounds like [`CHAR(26)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) would probably suit  your fixed-width string, like "5432543-88367-87366-637622".

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I was after the MySQL Datatype. So sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If its only for display and you don't have to break it apart, a string would be the best.

If you need it broken apart, create your own class then implement a `__toString` function.

Comment: Thanks Guys. What I'm trying to do is hold a unique number for users, the number looks like "5432543-88367-87366-637622". I recok a varchar would be good isnt it?